# Location aware and weather website. Problems with Javascript and cross site XML

Tags: javascript, xml, geolocation, weather

Trying to make a page where it shows current weather to a user via Javascript. So I have code that can find a users location and properly create a URL that will fit the convention for Google's weather API perfectly but the problem is making the xml request and presenting the weather data back to the user is proving a problem. I have installed mod_rewrite for apache to get around the cross site xml problem however it doesn't seem to be working properly. Anyone else have and idea how I could get this to work? Here is the code I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="robots" value="none" />
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="yourinfo">

</div>
<b>url:</b> <span id="url"></span><br />
<b>city:</b> <span id="city"></span><br />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(google.loader.ClientLocation)
    {
        visitor_lat = google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude;
        visitor_lon = google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude;
        visitor_city = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city;
        visitor_region = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region;
        visitor_country = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country;
        visitor_countrycode = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code;
        weather_http = 'http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=' + visitor_city + '+' + visitor_region;

        var Result = weather_http;

    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('yourinfo').innerHTML = '<p>Whoops!</p>';
    }


    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",'weather_http',false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

    document.getElementById("url").innerHTML=weather_http
    document.getElementById("city").innerHTML=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("city")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    </script>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What doesn't work?

Comment: Very hard for me to tell because I'm new to javascript and don't have an easy way to test it. It seems the URL comes back in the weather_http variable but when I do the GET request and try to parse it nothing gets written to the screen

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia has a great example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#The_onreadystatechange_event_listener) of how to set up a valid XMLHttpRequest.

Basically you need to set up an onreadystatechange listener for your request, then open the connection passing a URL (i.e: weather_http, not 'weather_http' as is in your code) and finally sending all your data.

Because XHR Requests are assynchronous, you have to implement that callback, so that the javascript engine knows what to do when the XHR responds.

When you get the XHR working, you'll discover that you can't do what you are trying to do without a proxy. That is because of the Cross Domain Policy for XHR. You can't get data via XHR from a domain different than the current domain of the application.

To get over that, you`ll need to implement a server-proxy to submit the XHR to the other domain, retrieve the response and give it back to your application. There are tons of proxies freely available, just [search google for it](http://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+cross+domain+proxy+php).

Finally you`ll have one last problem that is telling your proxy to append ?weather=city to the target URL.

Good luck!